# What's wrong with my code? Changing colour to a div slowly

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know why my code doesn't work? I want to change the color of a div slowly.

```
function fadein() {
    change = document.getElementsByClassName("load_1")[0]
    setInterval(function(){
        change.style.color = "rgb("+x+","+x+","+x+")";
        x=x+1
    }, 200)
};

function animate(){
    var x=0;
    fadein()
};

animate()
```

Comment: What's the error, and also what is change or index or x? The function doesn't know unless you declare them. You are also missing a few semicolons

Comment: `x` does not exist inside the `fadein` function, so it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing `x` like this

```
function fadein(x) {
    var change = document.getElementsByClassName("load_1")[0];
    setInterval(function(){
        change.style.color = "rgb("+x+","+x+","+x+")";
        x=x+1;
    }, 200);
};

function animate(){
    var x=0;
    fadein(x);
};

animate();
```

Comment: ;) it's the issue i start to write the same but you go faster than me

Comment: I didn't test it but it's a start.

Comment: Pretty sure var isn't required in js, but would be good practice. Thus, change is instantiated on the first line of fadein

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this way

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf8"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changecolor() {
 document.getElementById("color").style.cssText = "background:#008000; -moz-transition:all 1s; -webkit-transition:all 1s; -o-transition:all 1s; transition:all 1s;";
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<style>
#color {width:150px; height:150px; background:#f00;}
</style>
<div id="color"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="changecolor()" value="Change color"/>
</body>
</html
```

Just change **-moz-transition:all 1s;** with time from your choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really insisting on javascript, this is one way it can be accomplished. There are more elegant ways but this one will work. You can also use CSS transitions or jQuery animate.

```
var x = 0;

function fadein() {
    var change = document.getElementsByClassName("load_1")[0];
    setInterval(function(){
        change.style.color = "rgb("+x+","+x+","+x+")";
        x++;
        if(x < 256)
            fadein();
    }, 200);
};

function animate(){
    x=0;
    fadein();
};

animate();
```

Answer (score 1):

The minimal amount of steps to get this working, would be to:

- Declare the `x` variable outside the function
- Pass in a target color value to terminate the operation on. In this case, you need to clear the interval — otherwise the RGB will go on forever.

Here's an example:

```js
var x;
function fadein(target) {
    x=0;
    var change = document.getElementsByClassName("load_1")[0]
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        console.log("rgb("+x+","+x+","+x+")")
        change.style.color = "rgb("+x+","+x+","+x+")";
        x=x+1;
        if (x > target) clearInterval(interval);
    }, 100)
};

function animate() {
    fadein(255);
};

animate();
```

```html
<div class="load_1">Hello World</div>
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's best done with CSS.

```
.colorchange {
  animation: blacktowhite;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}
@keyframes blacktowhite {
  from {color: rgb(0,0,0);}
  to {color: rgb(255,255,255);}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7tzeynd0/

Answer (score 0):

Since this is your second question about animations, have a look at this rather generic solution:

- Use [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) for animations
- Synchronize your animations by using (provided) timestamps

```js
function fade(duration, callback) {
  let start = performance.now();
  let step = (now) => {
    let delta = (now - start) / duration;
    if (delta < 1) {
      callback(delta);
      requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

let loading = document.getElementById("loading");

fade(1000, (delta) => {
    let color = 255 * delta | 0;
    loading.style.color = `rgb(${color},${color},${color})`;
});
```

```html
<div id="loading">LOADING</div>
```